# CakePHP Layout a web app

Tags: cakephp

I'm working on an invoicing system using CakePHP, its fairly basic to start off with. I've used the Blog Tutorial (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started.html) as the basis for my project. I've also installed Twitter's Bootstrap framework.

I'm using tabs for navigation. So at the moment the user will have the following tab options:

Summary - Invoices - Expenses - Banking - Contacts - More

In the Apps->View folder I have a Contacts folder and an Invoices folder, these folders have the following files:

index.ctp - this is the general layout of the page i.e. for invoices and contacts its just a table listing all the entries from the database.

view.ctp - this displays a detailed view when the user clicks on a table entry.

add.ctp - each view has an add button and this script is the layout of the add page.

In the Apps->View->Elements folder I have the code for the tabbed navigation (tabs.ctp). I have the following line of code in  Apps->View->Contacts->index.ctp & Apps->View->Invoices->index.ctp:

```
<? echo $this->element('tabs'); ?>
```

This displays the tabbed navigation in each view.

In my App->Config->routes.php I have the following code:

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'invoices', 'action' => 'index'));
```

obviously this makes Apps->View->Invoices->index.ctp the initial page the user views.

But when the application loads, I can see the Invoices page with no issues, but when I try and click on the Contacts tab nothing happens. When I look at the source code, the contacts view code is not loaded.

I may have laid out the project incorrectly, so any help appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
Code from ContactsController.php:

```
<?php
class ContactsController extends AppController {
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session');
    public $components = array('Session');

    public function index() {
        $this->set('contacts', $this->Contact->find('all'));
    }

    public function view($id) {
        if (!$id) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid contact'));
        }

        $contact = $this->Contact->findById($id);
        if (!$contact) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid contact'));
        }
        $this->set('contact', $contact);
    }

    public function add() {
        if ($this->request->is('contact')) {
            $this->Contact->create();
            if ($this->Contact->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Your contact has been saved.');
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Unable to add your contact.');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
Sample code from routes.php:

```
/**
 * Here, we are connecting '/' (base path) to controller called 'Pages',
 * its action called 'display', and we pass a param to select the view file
 * to use (in this case, /app/View/Pages/home.ctp)...
 */
    //Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'));
    Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'invoices', 'action' => 'index'));   
/**
 * ...and connect the rest of 'Pages' controller's urls.
 */
    Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display')); 

/**
 * Load all plugin routes.  See the CakePlugin documentation on
 * how to customize the loading of plugin routes.
 */
    CakePlugin::routes();

/**
 * Load the CakePHP default routes. Only remove this if you do not want to use
 * the built-in default routes.
 */
    require CAKE . 'Config' . DS . 'routes.php';
```

Regards,
Stephen

Comment: At least one possible problem in your sample code: *don't* use PHP short opening tags; replace `<? echo` with `<?php echo`. Short opening tags are disabled on most servers and discouraged

Comment: Also, during development, set 'debug' to 1 or 2 inside `app/Config/core.php` look for this line inside that file: `Config::write('debug', 2);` the 2 is the *debug level*. Even better: install the official [Debugkit](https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit) plugin; it gives a lot more configuration that help debugging your code. It's possible that there's some error in your application (e.g. Missing Model or database table), but that this error is not showing because debug messages are disabled

Comment: @thaJeztah debug mode is turned on and I'm not getting any errors.

Comment: Did you create the `ContactsController` inside `app/Controllers/ContactsController.php`? Does it have a `index()` method and does it extend the `AppController`? Also, did you keep the 'default' CakePHP routes inside your routes.php?

Comment: Yes, I have created ContactsController.php, I've included the code above. I've commented out the default line in routes.php

Comment: If you disabled the default-routes, then `/Contacts/index` will not be routed to `ContactsController::index()`. However, if you kept them enabled, you can always add some 'debug' line inside `ContactsController::index()`, e.g. simply `debug('hello world');exit()' to verify that you get to the right action.

Comment: @thaJeztah I've included the routes.php code above, I don't think the line I've commented out will cause this issue.

Comment: You're right, that shouldn't cause a problem. Pretty hard to find what's wrong for me (from a distance). Try to use the debugging suggestions I gave. Check your log-files as well. And, it may be worth a try to change the '/' route to be connected to your Contacts controller?

Comment: Thanks @thaJeztah changing the route file just displays the contacts page as the initial page and then I can't navigate to the invoices page. I'll try the debug plugin.

Comment: Maybe it's a JS Problem. Do you check the Bootstrap stuff? (I don't use Bootstrap. It's only a guess)

Comment: @Mika Nothing wrong with the Bootstrap, its all working with no issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the link for the 'Contacts' tab you've created is correctly formatted. For example;

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('Contacts',array('controller'=>'contacts','action'=>'index'); ?>
```

Providing you have your rewrite rules correctly configured, the link should now work.

Answer (score 0):

you may also want to clear out your cake core caches, e.g.

```
app/tmp/cache/*/*
```

Comment: also, what happens when you go directly to the url /contracts/index ?

Comment: The page loads with no problems.